# Stuck in a login bootloop

Tags: boot, 16.04, login, login-screen

I recently installed an AMD graphics driver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop Version and ever since, I can't seem to log in. Every time I enter my credentials and hit enter, it blacks out for a second and then returns to the same login screen. I have tried all fixes listed here: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but nothing seems to work. This is what my .xsession-errors looks like:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3685) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (3670) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (3525) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (3668) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service (3668) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (3650) killed by TERM signal
```

And excluding the comments, this is what .profile looks like:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Can someone help? I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: So remove the AMD driver. It looks like you installed a wrong one.

Comment: Pretty sure it was the right one. I got it from their website for the exact processor that I am using. Would reinstalling help?

Comment: There is absolutely no information to tell...

Comment: ctrl+alt+f1 , login with username and pass and do: ls --block-size=k -l /var/log . there you will find the error log files. the one with the biggest size propably is the one with the information about your error. can you output the error ? if you use cat command you can view the content. we need more information on the problem otherwise we can't tell how to fix it

Comment: I ran "grep -r amdgpu-pro ." and stored the output into a file. Here's what it says: http://pastebin.com/udKvvmYv. Are you able to tell anything?

Comment: After I uninstalled the driver, it booted just fine. I reinstalled it and it started blacking out again. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, my processor is AMD R9 Nano and I am getting the matching driver from AMD's website (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) but I don't know what's wrong.